# How do I pass a variable in mysqli_multi_query?

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I'm trying to set a variable `number` from a mysqli query. And use the variable in the next query. I tried the following query, but in vain. What is the right way?

```
mysqli_multi_query($mysqli, "COUNT(fruits) FROM eatables as num SET @number= num; UPDATE fruits SET fruits = @number") or die('</br>mySqli Error</br>');
```

here is the sample sql database:

```
table eatables:

#fruits   #numbers
apple      null
apple      null
grapes     null
mango      null
pears      null
grapes     null
```

after the query, it should be

```
#fruits   #numbers
apple      3
apple      3
grapes     2
mango      1
pears      1
grapes     2
```

Answer (score 1):

multi query is not required for your case,
do an inner join for update will do

```
update eatables
inner join (select fruits, count(*) as total from eatables group by fruits) as b
on eatables.fruits = b.fruits
set eatables.numbers = b.total
```

Answer (score 0):

You should show more code context, though what it sounds like what you want to do is not how mysqli_multi_query is used.  It is intended to be used to execute a set of different queries that are passed in a string and give you the ability to work with each result set independently. It is not designed to where you loop over the same query X number of times changing the SQL statement in response to the execution of the previous statement.